# Fastest way to concatenate two large QVector's and sort them (C++/Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, concatenation, qvector

What is the best (fastest) way to concatenate two large already sorted `QVector`'s in one large sorted `QVector`?

I have the following code:

```
class Square
{
    .....
    qint32 id; //public
    .....
}

QVector <Square> v_one; //size 10000+
QVector <Square> v_two; //size 10000+
```

I have `v_one` and `v_two` already sorted by "`id`".

How do I perform a **FAST** merge of these two vectors into one of them (e.g. `v_one = v_one + v_two`) with sorting by **`id`**.

I think I have to do this as one action (sorting and merging), not one after another?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/ (either you use it directly, or you reimplement the algorithm therein described).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Looks like it will be extremely slow, no?

Comment: I would go multithread with the merge sort. The concatenation of both vectors can't be accelerated much but the sorting that follows can by using more than one of the cores on your system => merge sort is well suited for parallel sorting.

Comment: @VoronkovIvan: it's O(n) in the total number of arguments versus O(n log n) of any "regular" sort based solution, you are not going to beat this asymptotically. Incidentally, if we are talking about n~10000 anything will do, it's really small stuff for any cpu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to merge them in one of the two vectors, I'd suggest `std::inplace_merge`:

```
auto size_one = v_one.size();
v_one += v_two;
std::inplace_merge(v_one.begin(), v_one.begin() + size_one, v_one.end(), 
  [](Square const &a, Square const &b) -> bool
  { return a.id < b.id; });
```

For parallel execution: The experimental [C++ Extensions for Parallelism, ISO/IEC TS 19570:2015](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) has [`std::experimental::parallel::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing) which will probably be part of the standard some time in the future. You can find an [implementation for the parallel merge algorithms](https://parallelstl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#include/experimental/impl/merge.h) in the [CodePlex Parallel STL project](https://parallelstl.codeplex.com/) which is the Microsoft prototype of the Parallelism Extension.

---

Edit:

Removing duplicates can be achieved by using `std::unique`.

```
auto new_end = std::unique(v_one.begin(), v_one.end(), 
  [](Square const &a, Square const &b) -> bool
  { return a.id == b.id; });
v_one.erase(new_end, v_one.end());
```

Comment: Is `std::inplace_merge` multithreaded? Because if it is not I would rather concatenate the second to the first vector and then use a multithreaded merge sort to sort the whole thing.

Comment: Looks solid. I'll surely try this one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @rbaleksandar A multithreaded merge-sort threads the individual merges. This is one individual merge, not suitable for threading.

Comment: I think I might have expressed myself incorrectly. The OP wants to add the second vector to the first (or vice verse, or create a new one with all the elements from both). There is no point in using threads for this. It's the **sorting** that follows that can be done via multithreaded merge-sort that is merge-sort is applied to the newly created set of values made from both the vectors.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: Imo the merging of two sorted vectors can be regarded as the last merge step of a merge-sort of the whole range rather than a merge sort. Applying a merge-sort to the whole range would redivide the whole range into sub-ranges and try to sort them which is pointless if `v_one` and `v_two` are already sorted.

Comment: @Pixelchemist : Hello!  I have one more question. If i want to delete duplicates in result vector, how do i do this? Example:      v_one.erase(std::unique(v_one.begin(), v_one.end(), 
  [](Square const &a, Square const &b) -> bool
  { return a.id == b.id; });)          Is not working :(

Comment: @Pixelchemist . Thank you. I appreciate a lot.

Comment: @VoronkovIvan: If it answers your question appropriately, consider to accept my answer.